# Security on Google App Engine(Java) - Servlet SSL?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, servlets, ssl

Is it possible to use SSL one one of the servlet-mappings in web.xml?

I have a site using GWT for browser access and mobile phones accessing the gae via simple HttpServletRequest in servlets.

The setup:

1. Browser GWT Access

For the site, the user log in via Google Account or Facebook. Then the user interacts with the site - no SSL setup here as I am using Google App Domain. 
I guess the communication regarding user and password is safe in this senario with tokens etc. right?

2. Mobile Access

The user interacts with the Google App Engine(Java) from Mobile phones - the user and password is passed along each call. This I need to be SSL and safe.

---

I have seen thinks like this: [using https sparingly in my GAEJ app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264473/using-https-sparingly-in-my-gaej-app)

But I am not using RPC from the mobile access.

Any thoughts on this - Thanks in advance

Regards

Therefore I am thinking SSL on the Google Ap Engine, but is it posible in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use ssl with appengine but you have to use the *.appspot.com domain, not your own domain name.

See the following link for information about securing specific urls in appengine in web.xml
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs

hth

Comment: Well, I must have been staring myself blind on this one - I have looked at this doc many times.